# How restart the animation in UWP using Visible property?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

In a UWP app, I show an error bar in the bottom of the Window, like Mail app of Windows 10. The idea is when I change the Visibility to Collapsed, the animation would start.
The animation only works once, when the window is created. I would like to trigger the animation each time that Visibility changes from Visible to Collapsed. The XAML code is:

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Canvas.ZIndex="10"  Background="{StaticResource BackError}"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="NotificationStackPanel"  >
        <StackPanel.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <PaneThemeTransition  Edge="Bottom"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </StackPanel.Transitions>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="White" Margin="20"  Name="NotificationText"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

My workaround for now is removing the entire StackPanel and recreating it again, it works but it seems too ugly.

Comment: Transitions sadly don't offer a lot of interaction possibilities... If you want to use the `PaneThemeTransition`, you are doing it in the only possible way already.

Only Other option I can think if is to use a storyboard animation instead.

Answer (score -2):

[`PaneThemeTransition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh969160) is a transition animation. Usually we use panel animations (**PaneThemeTransition**) to show UI that slides a significant distance into the screen, such as a task pane or a custom soft keyboard.

Transition animations have built-in triggers (the transition) that can run automatically when UI elements are added, removed, reordered, and so on. Transition animations are simple to apply. But we do not have much control over the timing and order of the animation effects.

To restart the panel animation, you can remove the `StackPanel` form its parent element and then add it again like:

```cs
private bool isVisible = true;

private void ChangeVisibility()
{
    if (isVisible)
    {
        //Root is a Grid which is the parent element of NotificationStackPanel
        Root.Children.Remove(NotificationStackPanel);
    }
    else
    {
        Root.Children.Add(NotificationStackPanel);
    }
    isVisible = !isVisible;
}
```

Comment: -1 have you read the question? "My workaround for now is removing the entire StackPanel and recreating it again, it works but it seems too ugly."

Comment: @Markus OP Says "recreating it again", but there is no need to recreat it, so in my answer, I said **add it again** and I  think this is the onlyway to restart the panel animation. If you have a better approach, please share it!